# Water as a verb

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I saw an advertisement of a product which helps people clean their body without the need to use water. The advertisement was:

> We made easy way to clean, No need to water

Is it correct?

Comment: 'We made easy way to clean' sets the tone for what follows. A link to the original would help, so that the overall standard of English used may be estimated.

Comment: Googling "We made easy way to clean" only leads to this question. I have a feeling it was not copied correctly. If this was an advertisement, I think it would show up in more places.

Comment: @pipe I'd guess it's a rather poorly translated sentence to English or just a random ad on real-world shops, not a digital ad.

Comment: Depending on what the product is, the correct verb would probably be **"[rinse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rinse)."**

Answer (score 29):

*Water* can indeed be used as a verb. It means "giving water to something" as in:

> Watering the plants (pouring water on them so they don't dry out)

or

> Watering the horses (making the horses drink to quench their thirst)

The verb *water* is applied to (living) plants and animals, whereas *cleaning* is not something you usually associate with those.

Therefore I do not believe that *water* was used, or meant to be used, as a verb in your advertisement. The advertisement is not grammatical at all.

> We made easy way to clean

This is not a sentence any native speaker would utter. What was meant was probably something like

> We came up *with* an easy way to clean.

Since the first sentence is, although understandable, so clunky, I would assume that the second part also means something else:

> No need to water

They probably meant:

> No need for water

or possibly

> No need to apply water / No need to use water

Comment: The mishap maybe happed because in a dictionary "to water" was explained as "to apply water, to give water to sth" or similar. (In some languages you might "apply" water to plants and it means watering them, I guess.)

Comment: Or just "no water needed".

Answer (score 6):

The first half of the sentence "We made easy way to clean" gives it away as something not written by a native English speaker. Firstly it needs an article "We made an easy way". Secondly, "making a way" to do something is uncolloquial, you would usually talk about "inventing" or "developing" a way to do it. Thirdly, "to clean" would normally be transitive; or if you're talking about cleaning your own body, you would say "to wash".

A translation into colloquial English would be: "We made it easy to wash: no need for water".

Comment: Even "We made washing easier: no need for water"

Comment: ["Wash"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wash) implies the use of water (or some other solvent) for cleaning. "Cleaning" has no such implication.

Comment: The marketing version:  Ezy-Kleen™ - Water Free

Comment: @200_success I think Micheal has the colloquial translation right.  "Wash" does currently imply use of a solvent, whereas "clean" doesn't.  On the other hand "clean" is "clean something else" (unless you explicitly say "clean yourself").  A marketing slogan would be more concerned about the *aim* of the exercise than the means to achieve it.